# why the task scheduler can't export files

Tags: mysql

I need to export files from one server to another server daily. I use toad for mysql to create sql script, and put it in the automation(.tas) file. When I run it manually, it runs perfect, and export the files to the directory I want. However, when I put the .tas file in the task scheduler, it runs fine, but just won't export the files.

Appreciated for any advises.

Comment: missing privileges, maybe?

Comment: what privileges do I miss, how can I add it? BTW, I run the import.tas on the task scheduler at the same time, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

it works now, it turns out that in the my.ini file, the mysql client port number is different from the server one, I changed them to be the same one, and it works.